# Determining Profit Python

Tags: string, python-3.x, floating-point, string-formatting, currency-formatting

I am writing a program to determine a car salesman profit for a new or pre-owned vehicle.

- I need to express all three outputs in currency format with the **$** sign right up against the first digit and two decimal places.
- I need to add commas for any profit earned over $1000.
- The salesman gets 25% profit from a pre-owned sale and 35% profit from new sales.

**Pseudocode**

1. **Start Program**
2. The salesperson gets 25% dealer profit on pre-owned vehicles.
3. The salesperson gets 35% dealer profit
4. Enter the total dealer profit on pre-owned vehicles sold.
5. Enter total dealer profit on new vehicles sold.
6. The input type should `float`.
7. Compute and display commission amounts
8. Compute and display the total commission.
9. Print out the sum.
10. **End Program**

**Code so far**

```
def main():
    pre-owned_vehicles = float(input("Enter total profit on pre-owned vehicles sold * 0.25: "))
    new_vehicles = float(input("Enter total profit on new vehicles sold * 0.35: "))
    commission pre-owned sales = float(input("Enter commission pre_owned: "))
    commission new sales = float(input("Enter commission new: "))
    total = profit + commission
    print('Pre-owned sales profit is $')
    format(new sale profit, ',.2f)

main()
```

Comment: #START PROGRAM
#SALESPERSON GET 25% DEALER PROFIT ON USED VEHICLES
#SALESPERSON GET 35% DEALER PROFIT ON NEW VEHICLES
#ENTER TOTAL DEALER PROFIT ON PRE OWNED VEHICLES SOLD.
  pre-owned dealer profit = gross sale * .25
#ENTER TOTAL DEALER PROFIT ON NEW VEHICLES SOLD.
  new dealer profit = gross sale * .35
#INPUT SHOULD BE TYPE FLOAT (.2f)
#COMPUTE AND DISPLAY COMMISSION AMOUNTS + TOTAL COMMISSION

#PRINT OUT THE SUM.
#END OF PROGRAM

Comment: So what exactly is your question? Stack Overflow isn't here to teach you basic stuff like this, but to provide answers to specific, concrete questions that might also be useful to somebody else. We're not going to do your homework for you.

Comment: you are not doing my homework for me, i keep getting a syntax error when trying to run my program when i put in "pre-owned" and i not sure what i am doing wrong. i'm putting the word in correctly, no spelling errors. why would i get an error message for this one word

Comment: The `-` character is interpreted as a minus sign in Python, you can't have one in an identifier. You also can't have spaces. I strongly suggest that you read a tutorial on this stuff. There's a good one in the official documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a SyntaxError because you cannot have variable names with hyphens (or spaces) in between, it thinks you are trying to subtract. Thus, change your code to:

```
pre-owned_vehicles = float(input("Enter total profit on pre-owned vehicles sold * 0.25: "))
```

And carry on.

---

```
>>> foo-bar = 'foo-bar'
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to operator
>>> foo_bar = 'foo-bar'
>>>
```

Comment: i am noticing, i need to read more about symbols for python cause i keep getting my placement all wrong.  Currently reading Python 3rd edition, and   this is what i am following what you placed above but i still get the error on the prefix pre

Comment: i know this is basic for most on here i see, but i am trying to learn by asking questions anywhere i can ask, so i apologize if this is something below average in here.

Comment: Okay, i figured out my problem but now i am getting an error of "Can't assign operator", is there like a list i can find online that explains the different errors.